# Intent to inner class ( SettingsActivity)

Tags: android, android-intent, preferencefragment

In my Android app if a user is launching the app the first time I need the them to go to `SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment` to choose a country in the `PreferenceFragment` and then launch the app

How do I do this? I tried using

```
Intent A = newIntent(getBaseContext(), SettingsActivity.GeneralPreferenceFragment.class);
startActivity(A);`
```

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment"/>
```

When I run the app it give me this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myappname.app.SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: **GeneralPreferenceFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity** Isn't the error clear enough? I wish users would have read the errors before asking ...Anyways, Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Fragments aren't Activities. You can't `startActivity(Fragment)`.

If you need that Fragment to be displayed in your Activity, then you need to use some code and the FragmentManager to display it.

Answer (score 1):

The resource framework automatically selects the resources that best match the device. Such behavior is enough for common applications, so just make sure you have strict reasons to change it before proceeding further.

If you have a reason to do that, No need to use an activity, as a fragment (or `DialogFragment`) is sufficient for this activity sub-task. behind the scenes when you launch the app, you should restore the default `sharedPreference`, and retrieve your key for the language, and just show your fragment/dailog only if this key value is empty; or launch your app directly with the specific language you retrieved from this value.

No need to touch `manifest.xml` file nor to use an intent if you use a fragment/DialogFragment.